# Solid white screen after a simple PHP search query even though there is html

Tags: php, database

I'm making a very simple search program for my database.  When I run the query, if I search for data that I know is there, it returns the info I wanted it to and displays it.  If I enter data that I know does not exist, it goes to a solid blank page even though there is html behind it. Why?  Any clue?

I wish I had a better way to describe that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you turn on display errors at top of your PHP page?

```
ini_set ('display_errors', 1);
```

to see what it says? (Based on limited info, my guess is that query is crashing PHP).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a stab at that.